# Create a column that extracts specific words

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column called "Productdes" that holds thousands of rows with product description like:

Productdes

```
Varitas mágicas de Harry Potter  
Figuras de Star Wars  
Coleccionismo de Harry Potter  
Espadas de Juego de Tronos  
Bola de Dragon Z  
Estatuas de The Witcher (El Brujo)  
Figuras de Chucky El Muñeco Diabólico  
Cascos de Star Wars  
Espadas de The Legend of Zelda  
Estatuas de Los Vengadores (The Avengers)
```

I would like to create a new column called "Theme" that extracts for each corresponding row certain words from that row, like this:

```
Theme
Harry Potter  
Star Wars  
Harry Potter  
Juego de Tronos  
Dragon Z  
El Brujo  
Chucky El Muñeco Diabólico  
Star Wars  
Zelda  
Los Vengadores
```

I have used the following function but with no success:

```
mutate(Theme = str_extract(Productdes, 
                           c("Harry Potter",Star Wars","Juego de Tronos","Dragon Z",
                             "El Brujo","Chucky El Muñeco Diabólico","Zelda",
                             "Los Vengadores"))
```

I would appreciate any help please.
Thanks

Comment: You need to paste those strings together with `paste`

Answer (score 0):

We can `paste` the `vector` of strings to create a single single with delimiter `|` to be used as the pattern argument in `str_extract`

```
v1 <-  c("Harry Potter","Star Wars","Juego de Tronos","Dragon Z",
                         "El Brujo","Chucky El Muñeco Diabólico","Zelda",
                         "Los Vengadores")

df1$Theme <- str_extract(df1$Productdes, paste(v1, collapse="|"))
df1$Theme
#[1] "Harry Potter"               "Star Wars"                  "Harry Potter"               "Juego de Tronos"           
#[5] "Dragon Z"                   "El Brujo"                   "Chucky El Muñeco Diabólico" "Star Wars"                 
#[9] "Zelda"                      "Los Vengadores"
```